# Wordpress sort custom field values in alphabetical order

Tags: wordpress, sorting, custom-fields, alphabetical

I am using WordPress Custom Content Type Manager to build a Literary Agency website.

The page I'm stuck on is the Authors page which displays Thumbnails of all the books related to the author. The code i have below does just that, however I want it displayed in Alphabetical order. This is the code:

```
<?php if (get_custom_field("authimage:get_post")):?>
<div class="thumbstrip">
<h4>Titles by this Author</h4>
<ul>
<?php $my_post = get_custom_field("authimage:get_post");
    if(!empty($my_post)){
        foreach ($my_post as $a) {
            print '<li><a href="'. $a['permalink'] .'" title="'. $a['post_title'] .'"><img src="'.$a ['thumbnail_src'].'" /></a></li>';
        }
    }
?>
<ul>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

I've searched everywhere, but struggle adapting the solutions into my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$args=array(
      'meta_key' => 'authimage',  
      'orderby' => 'meta_value',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'numberposts' => 99
    );
    $thePosts = get_posts($args);
    $i=1;
    foreach($thePosts as $thisPost){
        $getPost = get_post($thisPost->ID);
         //Whatever you want to do with the post
    }
?>
```

Comment: For some reason, that section displaying the thumbnails went blank. I'm a little new to this. I need to know how to incorporate any solutions into my existing code. if you can show me with my code included that would be great. thanks